# Mapear array en otro que sea la suma de las cifras de cada numero js

Tags: javascript, array, map

He creado un array de números de más de una cifra y mi idea es mapearlo y que el nuevo array sea la suma de las cifras de cada número.

Ejemplo: Si tengo el array1 [20, 33, 48] el array 2 sería [2, 6, 12] ya que estoy sumando del primer array en primer lugar 2+0, en segundo lugar 3+3 y por ultimo 4+8.

Esto es lo que he llegado yo a hacer pero no me está dando el resultado.

```
let numeros_array = [20, 33, 48, 34, 55, 30];
console.log(numeros_array);
let numeros_array2 = numeros_array.toString();
numeros_array2.from;
numeros_array2 = numeros_array.map(x => x+x);
console.log(numeros_array2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```js
let numeros_array = [20, 33, 48, 34, 55, 30];
arraySumas = numeros_array.map( x => x.toString().match(/.{1}/g).reduce((SumaParcial, a) => SumaParcial + parseFloat(a), 0))
console.log(arraySumas)
```

donde:

- **arraySumas** será la nueva variable que contendrá las sumas
- **numeros_array.map** ejecutará una función para cada elemento del array
- En dicha función ponemos esto (al ser una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) el **return** va implícito):

```
x.toString().match(/.{1}/g).reduce((SumaParcial, a) => SumaParcial + parseFloat(a), 0);
```

donde con:

1. `toString()`: Convertimos a string el elemento del array mapeado en cada ciclo. [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)
2. `match(/.{1}/g)`: Separamos el string para convertirlo en un array de elementos de 1 carácter. [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
3. `reduce((SumaParcial, a)`: Reducimos ese array efectuando la siguiente operación en cada elemento:  ([Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce))
4. `SumaParcial + parseFloat(a)`: devuelve el valor del acumulador `SumaParcial` con el valor númerico del elemento pasado. [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)
5. `, 0);`: es el valor inicial del reduce.

Answer (score 3):

Ya te respondieron varios ejemplos de implementación. De una u otra manera todos hacen esto

Tenemos un array de números y queremos llegar a otro array compuesto de sus totales

```
[x1...xn]
  ┗━┓ 
    ┣━━━ y = numero_a_total(x)
  ┏━┛ 
  ┃ 
[y1...yn]
```

Tenemos que determinar una función `numero_a_total` que para un número `x` cuyos dígitos son `abc` calcula su suma

```
    numero_a_total(abc) = a+b+c
```

`numero_a_total` puede representarse como la combinación de varias funciones:

Una que convierte un número a su representación en string

```
  numero_a_string(abc) = 'abc'
```

Otra que convierte un string en un arreglo de caracteres

```
  string_a_caracteres('abc') =  ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Otra que convierte caracteres a digitos

```
  caracteres_a_digitos( ['a','b','c'])=[a,b,c]
  // que es lo mismo que
  ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(caracter_a_digito) =[a,b,c]
```

Y finalmente una que recibe un arreglo de dígitos y devuelve su suma

```
  suma_de_digitos([a,b,c]) = a+b+c
```

Que se puede modelar como un pipeline

```
abc = xn   ━━┓    
             ┃
             ┣━━ 'abc' = numero_a_string(abc)
             ┃
             ┣━━━ ['a', 'b', 'c'] = string a caracteres('abc')
             ┃                             
             ┗━━━ [a,b,c] = ['a', 'b', 'c'].map(caracter_a_digito)
             ┃                             
             ┗━━━ a+b+c = suma_de_digitos([a,b,c])
yn = a+b+c ━━┛
```

**Implementaciones de `numero_a_string`**. Todas son equivalentes:

```
  String(n)
  n.toString(10)
  ''+n
  n.toFixed()
```

---

**Para convertir ese `string` en `string[]`** (es trivial separar un string en sus dígitos) también te han dado ejemplos. Los siguientes son equivalentes

```
  str.split('')
  str.match(/\d/g)
  Object.values(str)
  `${n}`.split('')
```

**Mapear el resultado a un arreglo de números**. Son equivalentes

```
  Number(str)
  1*str
  parseFloat(str)
  parseInt(str,10)
```

**El meollo: sumar array de números**

Puedes usar cualquier loop

```
const suma1=(arr) => {
  let x=0
  for(let k of arr) {
    x+=k
  }
  return x
}
```

podemos inicializar x en el argumento, ahorramos una línea

```
const suma1=(arr,x=0) => {
  for(let k of arr) {
    x+=k
  }
  return x
}

const suma2=(arr,x=0)=>{
  while(arr.length) {
    x+=arr.pop()
  }
  return x
}
```

Si es por ponerse originales, a mí se me ocurrió esta:

```
const suma3=(arr,x=0) => arr.length? suma3(arr,x+=arr.pop()):x
```

pero `reduce` es el el método más conciso y elegante

```
const suma4=(arr)=>arr.reduce((total, k) => total+k, 0)
```

Y si quieres reprocesar un array sumando los dígitos de sus elementos, y del resultado un array sumando los dígitos de sus elementos, y así hasta tener una cifra por elemento, puedes hacer una recursión:

```js
const sampleArray=[...Array(6)].map(n=>5000+parseInt(Math.random()*5000,10))


/**
 * @param {number} cifra
 * @return {number}
 */
function collapse(cifra) {
  return  Object.values(String(cifra))
                .map(Number)
                .reduce((total,digito)=>total+digito,0);
}
/**
 * @param {number[]} arrIn
 * @return {number[]}
 */
function collapseRecursive(arrIn) {
  let arrayOut=arrIn.map(collapse)
  console.log(`[${arrIn.join(', ')}] => [${arrayOut.join(', ')}]`)
  return arrayOut.some(n=>n>9)? collapseRecursive(arrayOut):arrayOut;
}

collapseRecursive(sampleArray)
```

**Bonus Track**

Gracias a esta pregunta aprendí que `Array.from` acepta un segundo parámetro, una función (por defecto *identity*) para mapear los elementos del array que estás creando.

Lo siguiente consolida los pasos 'palabra_a_caracteres`y`caracteres_a_numeros` del pipeline en uno solo:

```
     Array.from('123',Number)
     // [1, 2, 3]
```

Así que podríamos resolver el problema con:

```
const numero_a_total= (x) => Array.from(String(x), Number)
                                  .reduce((accum,n) => accum+n, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Por pasos:

1. Se transforma cada número a String para obtener los dígitos.
2. Cada dígito se transforma en número de nuevo.
3. Se suman los dígitos.

Asumo que esto es un ejercicio para practicar, así que te daré una guía en lugar de resolverlo del todo:

```javascript
let numeros = [20, 33, 48, 34, 55, 30];

let sumasDeDigitos= numeros
  .map(String) //convierte a string
  .map( ... )  //convierte cada string en un array de Strings (1)
  .map( ... ) // suma los digitos de cada array (2)
```

Puedes usar en (1) el método [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
Puedes usar en (2) el método [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) para transformar la lista de digitos en su suma. Cuidado al sumar o acabarás concatenando.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui otra opción

```js
let numeros = [20, 33, 48, 34, 55, 30];

let result = numeros.map(num => [...num.toString()].reduce((acc, dig) => acc + Number(dig),0));

console.log(result)
```

El `.map` procesa cada numero en el array inicial.

El `[...num.toString()]` convierte el numero en caracteres individuales

El `.reduce` convierte cada digito a numero y lo suma